# How can I test that my component, which implements the standard modal components, is working properly?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-jest, lightning-base-component

Since the update to API 56.0 (Winter '23) Salesforce introduced a new set of components to help developers create modals with the Lightning Experience format in an easier way. The components added were the `lightning-modal` and its three children (header, body and footer).

A component that implements this new modal mode extends the `LightningModal` class and it implements the three sub-components on its body.

My problem is that I have content within the `lightning-modal-body` tags in my custom component, but those are not visible on a Jest test, apparently.

The component looks like this:

```js
<template>
  <lightning-modal-header label={header}></lightning-modal-header>
  <lightning-modal-body>
    <template if:true={items}>
      <!-- sldsValidatorIgnoreNextLine -->
      <lightning-tree-grid key-field="id" columns={columns} data={lineItems}>
      </lightning-tree-grid>
    </template>
  </lightning-modal-body>
  <lightning-modal-footer>
    <lightning-button
      label={labels.Save}
      onclick={handleOk}
      data-id="save"
      variant="brand"
      class="slds-var-m-around_xxx-small"
      ><label>{labels.Save}</label></lightning-button
    >
  </lightning-modal-footer>
</template>
```

On the test, if I assert that the modal body exists, it works:

```js
const modalBody = element.shadowRoot.querySelector("lightning-modal-body");
expect(modalBody).toBeTruthy();
```

But if I assert that the `lightning-tree-grid` exists within the body, it does not:

```js
const treeGridComponent = element.shadowRoot.querySelector(
  "lightning-tree-grid"
);
expect(treeGridComponent).not.toBe(null);
```

```
    expect(received).not.toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: not null

      63 |       "lightning-tree-grid"
      64 |     );
    > 65 |     expect(treeGridComponent).not.toBe(null);
         |                                   ^
      66 |   });
      67 | });
      68 |
```

So how does a test in this scenario should look like?

Comment: I really don't get why they required us to write an LWC that is the modal instead of being able to use the modal with some attributes and a body slot... I guess I'll find out when I try to use it (and will likely face the same issues you mention). Great question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured out the solution to this by following the concepts in the mocking [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/test-lightning-web-components/mock-other-components). Essentially we just need to make mocks for these components and tell jest to use them.

**1. Update sfdx-lwc-jest**

Be on the version that supports Winter 23, for example 1.1.4

**2. Make a directory to hold the mock components.**

The trailhead uses something similar to `force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning`

**3. Create mock component `.js` and `.html` files for the `lighting-modal-*` components.**

In the `.html` files include the following markup

```html
<template><slot></slot></template>
```

And in the `.js` files just stub out the components

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class ModalBody extends LightningElement {}
```

Your directory should have the following files:

```sh
/modalBody.html
/modalBody.js
/modalHeader.html
/modalHeader.js
/modalFooter.html
/modalFooter.js
```

**4. Add the `LightningModal` stub**

Create another file in the same directory called `modal.js`

The [contents of this file](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/d6c1b67a3da89bb131d359851ad137d462938e6d/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/modal.js) I took from the `lwc-recipes` repo

Your directory should now have the following files:

```sh
/modal.js
/modalBody.html
/modalBody.js
/modalHeader.html
/modalHeader.js
/modalFooter.html
/modalFooter.js
```

**5. Configure jest to use the mocks.**

In your `jest.config.js` file modify, or create, your `moduleNameMapper` to look like this pointing to your stubs

```json
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^lightning/modal$': '<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/modal',
    '^lightning/modalHeader$': '<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/modalHeader',
    '^lightning/modalBody$': '<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/modalBody',
    '^lightning/modalFooter$': '<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/modalFooter',
  },
```

After completing the above I was able to successfully test the content between the `lightning-modal-*` tags. You may get a warning in the console like

```sh
  The following files share their name; please delete one of them:
    * <rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/modalBody.html
    * <rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/modalBody.js
```

I'm just ignoring it, the linked trailhead has duplicate `.js`/`.html` files.

Answer (score 2):

For now, we do not have a way to test it, supposedly

> LightningModal provides an .open() method which opens a modal and returns a promise that asynchronously resolves with the result of the user’s interaction with the modal.
> Each invocation of a modal component’s .open() method creates a unique instance of the modal. You can think of a modal as a self-contained application that starts from scratch when it opens. It displays the content you pass in through the .open() method or that you set within the modal's HTML template. - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-modal/documentation

in other words, it is adding a new element to the DOM when the function .open() is fired:

Before opening:

[image: Before opening modal]

After opening:

[image: After opening modal]

ps.: the modal is a child node from lightning-overlay-container

Anyway, how we can "show" the modal? we need to call the .open() method from the implemented modal component, but when we are running tests it is not possible because we are mocking it, if you won't mock you will receive an error because it does not exist on your local machine:
[image: No mock]

Following the mock created by lwc-recipes (https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/modal.js) the open method mock only does one thing, throws an error, that's why is necessary to also mock the .open() function as well ->

```
LightningModal.open = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(YOUR STRING RETURN HERE);
```

Because of that, we do not actually have our modal on the screen, just their mock which doesn't have your lightning-tree-grid.

FYI here is their implementation of the modal, as you can see not even they have created the test for it (not until Today October 20 2022) https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/myModal

Comment: you also can try to use the modalBody function from the modal.js, but something is missing there:

    /**
     * Query select a single element in lightning-modal-body
     * Usage: `element.modalBody$('button')` Returns first button
     * @param {string} selectors Ex: 'div', 'button, [data-button]'
     * @returns element
     */
    @api
    modalBody$(selectors = '') {
        return select(this.template, LIGHTNING_MODAL_BODY, selectors);
    }

Comment: So the ideal scenario for testing this is to create a separate component to go between the body tags, and write the tests for that component separately? That's what I thought but wasn't sure.

Comment: for now, I would say yes, this is the best approach I can think of

Comment: I posted a new answer with a solution

Answer (score 1):

@TemporaryFix's solution works, but following [the docs for `lightning-modal`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-modal/documentation), we should use a slightly different approach. Use these methods on [the `modal.js` stub](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/modal.js) for selecting DOM elements inside the modal's header, body, and footer:

- `modalHeader$`

  - Equivalent to `element.shadowRoot.querySelector("lightning-modal-header").querySelector`
- `modalHeader$$`

  - Equivalent to `element.shadowRoot.querySelector("lightning-modal-header").querySelectorAll`
- `modalBody$`

  - Equivalent to `element.shadowRoot.querySelector("lightning-modal-body").querySelector`
- `modalBody$$`

  - Equivalent to `element.shadowRoot.querySelector("lightning-modal-body").querySelectorAll`
- `modalFooter$`

  - Equivalent to `element.shadowRoot.querySelector("lightning-modal-footer").querySelector`
- `modalFooter$$`

  - Equivalent to `element.shadowRoot.querySelector("lightning-modal-footer").querySelectorAll`

I tried running my test on the modal component without any manual mocking and got the `Cannot find module 'lightning/modal'` error. But as soon as I set up my `modal.js` stub per @TemporaryFix's answer, the following worked:

```js
expect(element.modalBody$("lightning-tree-grid")).toBeTruthy();
```

I did not have to create stub files for `modalHeader`, `modalBody`, or `modalFooter`, nor did I have to specify those files in my `jest.config.js`'s `moduleNameMapper`.

---

*Edit 12/19/2023: Depending on your `package.json` dependency versions related to LWC, it may still be necessary to stub out `modalHeader`, `modalBody`, and `modalFooter` as @TemporaryFix recommends. At the time I originally wrote this, I had recently used `npm-check-updates` to get the absolute latest versions of my dev environment dependencies. When I later had to revert due to issues with Prettier, I found that my Jest tests started throwing a `Cannot find module 'lightning/modalHeader'` error, so in the end I still had to stub those out. The test utility methods described above still worked, however.*

Answer (score 0):

I based my solution on the comment from @TemporaryFix, but instead of creating separate jest-mocks for the modal body/footer/header I only added a modal.js mock (copied from the recipe) and added a modal.html with slots:

```
<template> 
<slot></slot>
</template>
```